# Integrating a javascript pipeline to Django

Tags: javascript, django, webpack

I am trying this [tutorial](https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/integrating-javascript-pipeline/) to integrate  a modern JavaScript pipeline into a Django application. Javascript code is supposed to write a "Hello webpack" into the page, but it does not.

Since I already have an existing django project/app, I am writing on top of it.

`index-bundle.js` is created with the content at the end of this post. `django manage.py collect-static` collects it. https://mysite/static/index-bundle.js loads the js file. There is no console error message.

I see `<script src="/static/index-bundle.js"></script>` in the html generated, so everything should be fine.

What is wrong here?

index-bundle.js (comments deleted):

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ "./assets/index.js":
/***/ (() => {

eval("function component() {\r\n    const element = document.createElement('div');\r\n    element.innerHTML = 'Hello webpack';\r\n    return element;\r\n}\r\n\r\ndocument.body.appendChild(component());\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://project_dir/./assets/index.js?");

/***/ })

/******/    });
/******/    var __webpack_exports__ = {};
/******/    __webpack_modules__["./assets/index.js"]();
/******/    
/******/ })()
;
```

Comment: When you run the code, what happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @Flimm I expect to see the sentence "Hello Webpack". But nothing happens. As if the javascript is not run at all.

Answer (score 0):

It was working. I was looking to wrong place to see the sentence.